# Connecting to SAP ASE database with Prometheus sql_exporter

Tags: prometheus, sap-ase

I am attempting to use [this prometheus sql_exporter](https://github.com/burningalchemist/sql_exporter) to connect to a SAP ASE database.
I followed the instructions to add the [Go driver](https://github.com/thda/tds) for that database, rebuilt the binary, and updated the connection string to connect to the database.
I have it in this format
`data_source_name: 'tds://SAPSR3:mypassword@myHostname:4901/DBName`.

When attempting to view the metrics collected `curl localhost:9399/metrics`, I am seeing

> `ts=2023-04-17T16:47:17.947Z caller=klog.go:84 level=debug func=Infof msg="Error gathering metrics: [from Gatherer #1] context deadlineexceeded"`

Like the database connection is timing out. I am able to log into the DB using the same credentials for isql.

I tried updating the data source name format by removing the DB name, changing port, changing to `localhost` from the regular hostname, etc.

If I change the connection string, I see the error

> `ts=2023-04-17T17:33:02.764Z caller=klog.go:84 level=debug func=Infof msg="Error gathering metrics: [from Gatherer #1] Msg: 4002, Level: 14, State: 1\nServer: DBName, Line: 0:\nLogin failed.\n"`

So it seems to me that with the original data source name, it is making connection to the DB, otherwise the login would fail.

Is there something else I should be looking for in my ASE settings that could impact this?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be with the prometheus configuration (prometheus.yml).
try to first simply increase the scrape _interval, and scrape_timeout in the promtheus yaml file. this could help with the "context deadlineexceeded" you are getting.